# Listen to click event in Bootstrap DatetimePicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events, eonasdan-datetimepicker

Using http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/ I can't listen to a click event from inside the datepicker itself.

https://jsfiddle.net/minlare/6mxsgrqh/

```
$('input').datetimepicker();
$(document).on('click', function(e){
    console.log('clicked', e);
});
```

The click event does not propagate to the document when clicking inside the datetimepicker and I cannot see where the event is prevented from propagating.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('input').datetimepicker();
$(document).on('click', function(e){
console.log('clicked '+ e);
```

});

Use **+** in JS to concatenate strings.

Here is the [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6mxsgrqh/1/) .

Comment: The question does not relate to strings, but events and bubbling/propagation

Comment: this will bind click on whole body

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below:

```
$("body").click(function(event) {
    var $target = $(event.target);
    if ($target.is(".ui-datepicker") && $target.parents(".ui-datepicker").size() != 0) {
        /* click is from within a datepicker */ 
    }
});
```